# VBA code to search contacts on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, search

I am creating a workbook that has an add and search area on the first sheet and on the second sheet a contact list that has; last name, first name, #, address, and email. I have figured out how to add contacts to this sheet but I am cant figure out how to search this list(second sheet) for contacts form the first sheet also and have it display back on the first sheet. I know I probably need a string but don't know how to set it up.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

you could probably use this code:

```
Dim rfound As Range
On Error Resume Next
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rfound = .Columns(1).Find(What:=ComboBox1.Value, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False)
On Error GoTo 0
If rfound Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.Goto rfound, True
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = rfound.Offset(0, 0)
```

in this Code you use column for your data(Search for the Last Name, First Name, #, Address, and e-mail. you could use one of these columns to search for the whole row)

you could use an ActiveX Control to search for your data or just use a cell, in the code I used a ComboBox which has the array of a specific column for easier searching.

code for the ComboBox:

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
wb.Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ComboBox1.RowSource = wbo.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2", Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A65536").End(xlUp)).Address
```